# Access denied for user - (using password: NO)

Tags: php, html, connection

Hi I'm trying to connect to my database to use my registration form but im having no luck. When I run connection.php it displays the message: **Access denied for user ''@'10.246.64.24' (using password: NO)**

any tips much appreciated :)

**connection.php:**

```
<?php
$servername = "c3438525.co.uk.mysql";
$username = "c3438525_co_uk";
$password = "password";
ob_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("c3438525.co.uk.mysql", "c3438525_co_uk", "password", "c3438525_co_uk");

if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $con7>connect_error);
}
echo "Connected Successfully";
mysql_select_db( 'c3438525_co_uk' ) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

and my **registrationsubmit.php**

```
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php

include 'registrationform.php';
include 'connection.php';
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['regsubmit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //Insert into database the values entered in the registration form.
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password) VALUES ("$firstname","$lastname", "$username", "$password")"  
}
  Echo "Registration Successful - Press the Home button to return to the homepage.";

}
?>
</center>
```

Comment: bear in mind im not using the variables at the top in this code because I was changing a few things around to get it to work but no luck

Comment: you have syntax error at line 10 (start with die), It should be:
die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);

Comment: look at this example: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_connect(...
mysql_select_db('c3438525_co_uk'
```

You're mixing mysqli with functions from the old mysql extension. That doesn't work.
Since there has been no connection established via mysql_connect, the mysql extension tries to establish the default connect when mysql_select_db is called. Hence the `user ''@'10.246.64.24' (using password: NO)` message.
Remove all mysql_* functions and use only the mysqli versions.

Btw: in your second script (as posted) the query is not actually sent to the mysql server. But it's probably not the "real" script anyway, since it would cause a parse error because of the double-quotes within the dobule-quoted string literal.

But while you're at it, please also have a read of http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection